# Does sitting too much causes hip pain?

Tags: pain, sedentary-lifestyle, sitting

This is my first question here, and I don't know if here is a right place for it. 
I am a student, and I study software engineering, so I have to sit down for a long time a day, to study, and I study more than 6 hours usually. about 6 months ago, I experienced a sudden, chronic pain, in my hip, outer side and close to my leg. it lasts about 3 or 4 minutes, then I was alright again. but now frequency of the pain is getting more, it happen on both sides, and there is no situation that trigger that! sometimes, I am trying to sleep! or sometimes I am standing still! it may happens any time. the pain is just like the pain of injection, but it remains for about 30 seconds, to sometimes 5 minutes.

is it because of sitting too much? and if it is, what should I do?

Comment: Welcome to health stack exchange:-), you actually posted this question in the right stack exchange. And your question will surely be answered. Feel free to comment on any answers given if it doesn't actually meet your expectations

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). It seems that the frequency of your symptoms is increasing. Surely, sedentary lifestyle isn't the healthiest one but still the cause of your symptoms can't be identified over the internet. You should consult with your doctor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hips suffer from prolonged sitting, becoming tight and limited in range of motion because they are rarely extended. In the elderly, decreased hip mobility is a leading cause of falls.

Sitting also does nothing for your glutes, which may become weakened, affecting your stability and the power of your stride when walking and jumping.

Nerve irritation- The major nerves controlling lower leg function cross the hip. Irritation of these nerves can cause pain through the hip and/or down the leg. Injury to the sciatic nerve frequently causes pain along the outer thigh or down the back of the leg; this is called sciatica

In short, at the molecular level, your body was designed to be active and on the move all day long. When you stop moving for extended periods of time, it's like telling your body it's time to shut down and prepare for death.

HIP PAIN RELIEF

If pain is troublesome, you can take a pain medication such as acetaminophen(Tylenol). A non-steroidal anti-inflammatory drug(NSAID) such as ibuprofen(e.g Advil, Motrin), or naproxen(e.g Aleve) can also be used for pain

http://fitness.mercola.com/sites/fitness/archive/2015/05/08/sitting-too-long.aspx

https://www.uptodate.com/contents/hip-pain-beyond-the-basics#H1